# Awesome WM - Launch a terminal based app with a shortcut

Tags: bash, awesome, lua

What I want is to have a shortcut to initiate things like vifm, cmus, htop etc. These apps require being initiate from a terminal.

I know for create a shortcut in Awesome WM I should:

```
awful.key({ modkey },            "my_hotkey",     function () awful.util.spawn(...here goes the app) end,
          {description = "the_description", group = "my custom group"}),
```

But I can't simply put there:

```
awful.util.spawn("vifm")
```

I doesn't work. So how could I make a shortcut that initiates let's say vifm, taking in consideration this code have to run a terminal first and then inside that terminal launch "vifm".

Also, is there a more efficient way to do this? I mean maybe initiating directly vifm instead of having to rely on running first a terminal?

PD: My shell is bash, my terminal is Konsole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little embarrassed for not having realize the solution before. In fact it was in the very help page of konsole, anyways the command is (for konsole):

```
konsole -e cli_based_app
```

So for example

```
konsole -e vim
```

Then you can put that in your rc.lua and assign a hotkey for it.

Answer (score 0):

Most terminals allow running a command which, when finished, will also exit the terminal. I don't know Konsole, but in GNOME Terminal this is as simple as `gnome-terminal -- vim`.

If you want the terminal to hang around after the command is finished, you can use this hack: `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'vim; bash'`.

Comment: But for being able to use those apps, I need the terminal to stay. Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. Basically what I want is set a hotkey from Awesome to initiate a terminal(CLI) based apps.